# Windows 7 fails to see my Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, windows, usb-connection-mode

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and a Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III (rooted Android 4.1.2). When I plug the phone to the computer's USB port, I can't access the phone through Windows Explorer.

I installed the [latest Samsung USB drivers](http://androidxda.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers). I used to be able to access the phone through Windows Explorer before somebody SIM unlocked the phone. I'm not entirely whether the process to SIM unlock created the issue but it occurred pretty much at the same time.

Samsung drivers seem to be correctly installed:

[image: enter preformatted text here]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have this issue with two different computers. What can I try to fix it?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.